# Is it possible to use an Eventbridge pipe to target and SNS topic in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipe, aws-event-bridge

Much like the title says, I've been tasked with helping with a server less messaging system.

In Account A we have an SNS topic that sends messages via a cross-account subscription to a SQS topic in Account B.

This feeds an EC2 that does some business logic then outputs a message to another SQS queue in account B, I'd like to forward that message using Event-Bridge pipes from the sqs output queue in B back to the SNS in account A but get the following error when trying to deploy which seems to imply this isn't allowed.

{"ValidationErrorFields":[{"Name":"Target","Message":"Creating cross-account pipe is not permitted."}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, it should be possible - https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-cross-account.html

Have you looked at this documentation?

Probably you are just missing the configuration of permissions on the event bus where you are receiving the events.

Comment: This is the issue, we're not sending messages back to an Eventbus, but to a SNS topic. 

SNS (Acc A) - > SQS_1 (accB) -> EC2 -> SQS_2 (Acc B) - > Eventbridge Pipe -> SNS (Acc A) 

I've thrown together a lambda to forward messages to the SNS topic instead.

You'll notice that under the Eventbridge pipes documentation it specifies that Eventbuses must be in the same account - https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-event-target.html

Comment: On the link I sent you, it clearly states there - "You can send and receive events between event buses in Amazon accounts within the same Region in all Regions and between accounts in different Regions as long as the destination Region is a supported cross-Region destination Region."

Comment: So, you could probably consider doing EventBridge Account B -> to EventBridge Account A and then sending those events to wherever you want on Account A, including SNS (Acc A). In this scenario, you don't need to rely on lambda functions and manage the function, code, deployment, etc.

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to account A, so converting that SNS topic to eventbridge (and it's multiple subscriptions) is somewhat beyond scope

Comment: Ok that's fair enough. But answering your original question, it is possible to for EB to target SNS in another account, as per the documentation shared. If you agree, can you please mark the reply as answer so we can close this thread? Thanks